# Web analytics + KRL =?

Tags: analytics, krl

What would happen if you used KRL to inject web analytics into various sites using a proxy end point? Is it possible to track multi-site usage with a Kynetx implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the analytics package you are using. [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) uses a tracking code, rather then domain only, for tracking. They even have a way do your tracking in a way that does not interfere with the site if they also use Google Analytics. Their docs on [tracking events on multiple domains](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503) might be relevant.

It really comes down to how the tracking engine works. Give it a try, and remember to check and see if sites using the same engine are tracking as well (consult FireBug or Chrome Dev tools to look for the appropriate requests), to be a good neighbor.

Comment: Nice - thanks Sam! The multiple domain document was exactly what I was looking for. Have you played with Google Analytics and KRL at all?

Comment: Not yet, but it's on my list.